# Why wrap_content has no effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-wrap-content

Set `wrap_content` in `RecycleView` holder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubbleblue170x140_2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But text in `TextView` is not wrapped, there is a lot of empty space in the bubble, inside TextView.

[image]

How can I force to see something like this in iOS version:

[image]

In Android using `9-patch` image as `background`.

Comment: Off the cuff, your 9-patch PNG is too tall. 9-patch PNGs expand but do not shrink. The text width is set to `match_parent`, so I assume your concern is the extra vertical whitespace on the `wrap_content` height.

Comment: in TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
and use 9-patch PNG

Comment: The TextView *can't be smaller* than the 9 patch. That's the *minimum size*.

Answer (score 1):

The height of your text view is wrap and the big size is becuase of your 9patch image (probably having a big size)

And the width of that is match parent as you wanted in xml layput.

Just change the size of your 9 patch and make the width wrap content too

Answer (score 0):

Resize your 9patch. You should also change the `RelativeLayout`'s height and width to `wrap_content`. Or, even better, you should remove the `RelativeLayout` (it seems useless).